# How can I refresh a connected database table after executing a query

Tags: mysql, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have a windows form in Visual Studio 2012. I've connected it to a MySQL database. After executing an insert query, I need to refresh the table for a "select * from" query. How can I refresh the table without manually refreshing it in MySQL??

Comment: Which component are you using to execute your comands? An `Adapter` or a `Command`? Also are you using typed `DataSet`?

Comment: And what do you mean by "manually refreshing it in MySQL"?

Comment: I'm using Command for insert. For select query I'm using Adapter. The row created after insert command is not automatically displayed in the database. I have to refresh the table to see the newly created row. My doubt is, is there any query to refresh the table so I can select the newly added row?

Comment: You are mixing up things here. Saying that the inserted row is "not automatically displayed in the database" is incorrect. You probably mean it is not displayed by the application, the same application that you're issuing your insert command from. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. But my queries are executed in visual studio. And my database is in MySQL. When I execute the insert command, a row is created in MySQL. And then I use select query but it doesn't return any rows as the database is not refreshed. Only after refresh can the new row be displayed. Without displaying I can't perform the select query. I want to know if there is any way to refresh a table in MySQL through a Visual Basic command

Comment: Let me say it again. You don't need to *refresh* a table/database. When you issue an `INSERT` command from a client, your table is immediately updated and the new record will be returned by the database if you re-query it from the client. To re-query, you simply run your `SELECT` command again. If you're using an Adapter, you should simply call `Fill()` function again and it will get new records for you.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Thanks for the help!!!